# Jump when initially adjusting UITextView frame size in UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uiviewanimation

I have the following code to expand a text area & it's superview whenever the user taps on the field & editing begins:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    textView.text = @"";

    CGRect titleViewFrame = self.titleLabel.frame;
    titleViewFrame.size.height = kExpandedSubviewFrameHeight;

    CGRect titleTextViewFrame = self.titleTextView.frame;
    titleTextViewFrame.size.height = kExpandedSubviewFrameHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
        animations:^{
                         self.titleLabel.frame = titleViewFrame;
                         self.titleTextView.frame = titleTextViewFrame;
        }];
}
```

Everything works fine except the very first time the user taps this field, the y origin of the text view jumps up bit:

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you making adjustments for the keyboard as well? If so then you should get the timing, duration and size from the willShow notification.

Comment: No, the fields are high enough to not need to adjust for keyboard. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to animate only the titleView frame, and not the textView frame (since no borders). Set the textView frame with in the completion block of the animation.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I just had the same issue when resizing a uitextview and think it is related to the scrolling of the text view. This is my code that has 0 bounce when animating the height. I use an NSLayoutConstraint to adapt my height.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGSize size = [messageView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(messageView.frame.size.width, FLT_MAX)];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                     animations:^{
                         messageHeightConstraint.constant = size.height;
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [messageView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([messageView.text length], 0)];
                     }
    ];

}
```